# I want the slash to be between the two small boxes

Tags: html, css, forms

I have made a form using HTML, this is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.your-class input{
  float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="your-class">
<label><b>aspect ratio:</b></label>
<input type="number" name="no1"  min="0.25" style="width: 4em" step="any" placeholder="value1" required>
<b>/</b>
<input type="number" name="no2" min="0.25" style="width: 4em" step="any" placeholder="value2" required><br><br>
</div>
<label><b>value3:</b></label>
<input type="number" name="no3" min="0.25" step="any" placeholder="value3" required><br>
<input type="hidden" name="calculator_ok" value="ok">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" style="background-color: BurlyWood"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the symbol (`/`) to be between the two small boxes not after them, see the picture:
[image: form sample]

How should I edit the code to get that result?

Comment: Remove the `.your-class input {float:left;}` CSS rule...

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because of the "float: right" CSS rule; it is floating all the `<inputs>` to the left, and leaving everything else untouched.

A few options to make it work:

- The float could be removed;
- The slash could be placed inside a container and the CSS rule adjusted to apply to that container, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would have to turn *all* children into left floats...

```
<style>
    form > div, form > label, form > input, form > b  {
        float:left;
    }
</style>
```

However, floats are rather “out of fashion“ (in favor of i.e. flexbox).
Although in this case, a far simpler inline-block will do, to line up the inputs and the inside b-Tag.

(and you can avoid the `<b>`'s inside the labels by styling the labels)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        label {
            display: block;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        form > input, form > b  {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="your-class">
        <label>aspect ratio:</label>
        <input type="number" name="no1"  min="0.25" style="width: 4em" step="any" placeholder="value1" required>
        <b>/</b>
        <input type="number" name="no2" min="0.25" style="width: 4em" step="any" placeholder="value2" required><br><br>
        </div>
        <label>value3:</label>
        ...
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use html entity of `/` which is `&#47;`  instead